# Line plot with a color gradient between two fixed ends

Tags: r

I have a plot that represents the water level (y) over time (x) contained within a tank. Knowing the minimum level and the maximum level of the tank, I would like to create a color gradient of the level line from blue (when the level is near zero) to red when the level is near the maximum.

For example, the limit values of the tank are `y_min = 0.00m` and `y_max = 3m` and the graph oscillates in this case between 0 and 1.20m so that the shades of red should not appear. 
Could you kindly help me?  I am attaching some data from the data.frame to create the graph. Thanks so much.

[image]

```
TANK (data.frame)
       $datetime         $level  $variables $values $time
16  2014-06-28 17:56:00    0.00 Q_INGRESSO    0.41  0.25
17  2014-06-28 17:57:00    0.01 Q_INGRESSO    0.91  0.27
18  2014-06-28 17:58:00    0.01 Q_INGRESSO    1.77  0.28
19  2014-06-28 17:59:00    0.02 Q_INGRESSO    0.65  0.30
20  2014-06-28 18:00:00    0.03 Q_INGRESSO    2.42  0.32
21  2014-06-28 18:01:00    0.04 Q_INGRESSO    3.78  0.33
22  2014-06-28 18:02:00    0.06 Q_INGRESSO    5.63  0.35
23  2014-06-28 18:03:00    0.10 Q_INGRESSO    7.21  0.37
24  2014-06-28 18:04:00    0.15 Q_INGRESSO   23.17  0.38
25  2014-06-28 18:05:00    0.24 Q_INGRESSO  123.99  0.40
26  2014-06-28 18:06:00    0.41 Q_INGRESSO  376.17  0.42
27  2014-06-28 18:07:00    0.56 Q_INGRESSO  656.24  0.43
28  2014-06-28 18:08:00    0.64 Q_INGRESSO  891.72  0.45
29  2014-06-28 18:09:00    0.77 Q_INGRESSO 1469.96  0.47
30  2014-06-28 18:10:00    0.85 Q_INGRESSO 1955.89  0.48
31  2014-06-28 18:11:00    0.97 Q_INGRESSO 2333.80  0.50
32  2014-06-28 18:12:00    1.05 Q_INGRESSO 2558.26  0.52
33  2014-06-28 18:13:00    1.10 Q_INGRESSO 2793.53  0.53
34  2014-06-28 18:14:00    1.12 Q_INGRESSO 2935.18  0.55
35  2014-06-28 18:15:00    1.13 Q_INGRESSO 2967.78  0.57
36  2014-06-28 18:16:00    1.14 Q_INGRESSO 2978.83  0.58
37  2014-06-28 18:17:00    1.13 Q_INGRESSO 2964.84  0.60
38  2014-06-28 18:18:00    1.13 Q_INGRESSO 2945.94  0.62
39  2014-06-28 18:19:00    1.13 Q_INGRESSO 2910.81  0.63
40  2014-06-28 18:20:00    1.12 Q_INGRESSO 2859.38  0.65
41  2014-06-28 18:21:00    1.11 Q_INGRESSO 2798.38  0.67
42  2014-06-28 18:22:00    1.10 Q_INGRESSO 2718.95  0.68
43  2014-06-28 18:23:00    1.08 Q_INGRESSO 2621.13  0.70
44  2014-06-28 18:24:00    1.07 Q_INGRESSO 2531.05  0.72
45  2014-06-28 18:25:00    1.05 Q_INGRESSO 2428.74  0.73
46  2014-06-28 18:26:00    1.04 Q_INGRESSO 2321.52  0.75
47  2014-06-28 18:27:00    1.02 Q_INGRESSO 2212.85  0.77
48  2014-06-28 18:28:00    1.00 Q_INGRESSO 2104.01  0.78
49  2014-06-28 18:29:00    0.98 Q_INGRESSO 1999.15  0.80
50  2014-06-28 18:30:00    0.97 Q_INGRESSO 1895.27  0.82
51  2014-06-28 18:31:00    0.95 Q_INGRESSO 1804.06  0.83
52  2014-06-28 18:32:00    0.94 Q_INGRESSO 1713.20  0.85
53  2014-06-28 18:33:00    0.92 Q_INGRESSO 1636.14  0.87
54  2014-06-28 18:34:00    0.90 Q_INGRESSO 1560.66  0.88
55  2014-06-28 18:35:00    0.89 Q_INGRESSO 1492.37  0.90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a different data set to demonstrate the effect I think you're after:

```
d <- tibble(x=0:100, y=100*dweibull(0:100, 3, 40))
d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_colour_gradient(low="blue", high="red")
```

Giving
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that in this way the maximum value and the minimum value correspond to those contained in the graph, while I would like them to be set at `y_min = 0.00m` and `y_max = 3m`, although the graph only oscillates between 0 and 1.20, in this way I know how much the level has reached the maximum possible or not.

Comment: OK.  That needs just a little tweak:  adding `limits=c(0, 3)` to the scale definition fixes `red` at `3` rather than at the observed maximum.  Apologies for not picking up on that first time round.